# Attask task history- Is there a way to get updated log or history Of a task?

Tags: attask

Does task/issue contain a reference to its history, as in partcilar field is added at this particular time ?  Or is there a log maintained for updates in the task ?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the update feed on a task/issue to display when a field is changed or not. You can do this from within setup > interface > update feeds.

You can setup for example to log when a particular field is edited.

Comment: Does that apply for log time (hours field) as well ? As I am fetching task lastupdated from particular times tamp ... But when I am adding log time (hours field) to the task, that task do not appear in last updated. Hope there is a way to get only log time changes in the task..

Comment: adding hours to a task does not count as a last update on the task so the lastupdatedate field will not change when applying hours.

Answer (score 0):

Nams, consider polling the hours entered since the last timestamp of interest, "AND" fir the TaskID of interest.

Regards,
Doug